# Getting p-values from mgcv GAM result and calculating their average

Tags: r, statistics, gam

I'm doing many GAM model calculations (mgcv). Their output looks like the attached image. What I want to do is 1) to get only p-values from the output and 2) calculate their average. For example, in the case of the image, I want to get 0.0477 and 0.1518 and get their average (0.09975). I can do one calculation manually but I have many models and want to do it automatically.

I did look at pages like below but I get p-values different from the summary.

(added)

The format of GAM model I used is:

```
model1 <- gam(dependentx  ~ s(independent1) + s(independent2), data=datatable, method = "REML", bs='cr', family=Gamma(link=log))
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389900/extract-p-value-from-gam-check-in-rhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389900/extract-p-value-from-gam-check-in-r

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not given us *any* code to show what you are doing. Please try and include a reproducible example in your questions. I'll use the first example from `help(gam)`, which ends with `b`:

```
> b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),data=dat)
```

Then if you do:

```
> sb = summary(b)
```

and look at:

```
> sb$s.table
           edf   Ref.df         F       p-value
s(x0) 2.500168 3.115115  6.920610  1.293448e-04
s(x1) 2.401079 2.983817 81.857629  9.886217e-46
s(x2) 7.697714 8.564323 88.157916 4.267512e-130
s(x3) 1.000000 1.000000  4.343072  3.780565e-02
```

you should be able to see that the fourth column:

```
> sb$s.table[,4]
        s(x0)         s(x1)         s(x2)         s(x3) 
 1.293448e-04  9.886217e-46 4.267512e-130  3.780565e-02
```

Is the p-values printed by `summary`:

```
> summary(b)

[...]

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
        edf Ref.df      F  p-value    
s(x0) 2.500  3.115  6.921 0.000129 ***
s(x1) 2.401  2.984 81.858  < 2e-16 ***
s(x2) 7.698  8.564 88.158  < 2e-16 ***
s(x3) 1.000  1.000  4.343 0.037806 *  
[...]
```

If you want the mean of the p-values from a `gam` model in one line then it looks like:

```
> mean(summary(b)$s.table[,4])
[1] 0.009483748
```

but if that doesn't work for you its because you've not shown us how you are creating your model object.

Comment: Thank you for the code. The code works fine and it saves a lot of my time! I added a GAM model format that I am using in my calculations.